# Xmonad keybindings for thunderbird and dmenu

Tags: xmonad

I've been trying to get these two keybindings to work on my Xmonad setup for a while now, but alas I have failed. I want thunderbird to spawn on a certain workspace and demenu to run on the workspace that is currently being viewed. Here is the relavent part of my current keybinding setup:

```
keys' conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modmask = modmask}) = M.fromList $
  [  ((modMask, xK_d), spawnOn "2:Web" "dwb")
  ,  ((modMask, xK-r), spawn "dmenu_run")
  ,  ((modMask, xK_e), spawnOn "3:Email" "Mail"
...other keybindings that work.....
  ]
```

The dwb keybinding does work. In the thunderbird one, in place of "Mail" I have also tried "thunderbird" and "Thunderbird" to no avail.

I would certainly appreciate it if anyone can make this work for me. It gets annoying opening up thunderbird from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you type from the terminal to open Thunderbird should work as the third parameter of `spawnOn`. If all else fails, try the full path to the thunderbird executable.

For others who might google this, if don't know what to type in a terminal to launch a program, launch however you normally launch it (e.g. from a menu or using a key binding), and then type `ps -ef` to find the name of the command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to replace "Mail" with "thunderbird"

   ```
   ,  ((modMask, xK_e), spawnOn "3:Email" "Mail"
   ```

   To

   ```
   ,  ((modMask, xK_e), spawnOn "3:Email" "thunderbird"
   ```
2. If it still doesn't work, check if some other key configuration overwrite the key "e".

Answer (score 0):

[The default config](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/src/XMonad-Config.html) maps (modMask, xK_e) to "Switch to physical/Xinerama screen 2". Be sure you disabled/changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cli tool `xprop` and click on Thunderbird, it shows you the Class name of Thunderbird, which you need to place here:

```
,  ((modMask, xK_e), spawnOn "3:Email" "ClassName"
```